# Is it possible to limit accessing posts to its own writer?

Tags: django, django-admin

In my Django admin, I have a column, `created_by`, which is for who made a post. I have many people who can access Django admin to make posts. The problem is that it is possible for them to edit each other's posts right now.

I want them to be able to edit only their each own posts, not others' posts. Is there anyway to limit access permission to a specific user in Django admin?

Also, here's my codes for `admin.py` and `models.py`.

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Store)
class StoreAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = '__all__'
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size': '91'})},
    }
    list_display = ('id', 'status', 'businessName',
                    'typ', 'author', 'updated_by', 'created_by', 'updated_at', 'created_at')
    list_filter = ('businessName',)
    search_fields = ('businessName',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # adding the entry for the first time
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
        # updating already existing record
        else:
            obj.updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Store(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    created_by = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, editable=False,
                            related_name='stores_of_created_by', null=True, blank=True)
    updated_by = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, editable=False,
                            related_name='stores_of_updated_by', null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should override the **`get_queryset()`** method of **`ModelAdmin`** as below

```
@admin.register(Store)
class StoreAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    # your code
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return super(StoreAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).filter(created_by=request.user)
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return someting 
    # your code
```

Comment: Can I assign the access limit to specific users, not just current user? I'm the admin in the system, and I have a coworker to manage other people's posts. So, some people should be able to check all posts, and some other people must check their own posts.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible by ***adjusting the `.filter(...)` accordingly***

Comment: I don't know if I understood your answer, but I think If I use `.filter(...)`, it's gonna be applied to every user no matter it's admin, staff or regular user. When I log in my manager account, I want to see every stores created by every user, but when I log in one of our accounts that make posts, I wanna see posts created by 'that" account.

Comment: You'll get those *flags* by accessing `request.user`. (see my update)

Comment: Great! Thank you JPG!